# Problem moving vertex on Arrangement using Arrangement_accessor

Tags: c++, data-structures, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm trying to move some vertex in an arrangement using an `Arrangement_accessor`. What I did so far is:

```
ArrangementAccessor acc(*(self.arr)); // I'm using Objective-C++
Point_2 newPoint = toPoint_2(mouse);

// Change the vertex position
acc.modify_vertex_ex(v, newPoint);

// adjust all incident curves
Arrangement_2::Halfedge_around_vertex_circulator curr, first;
curr = first = v->incident_halfedges();
do {
    Point_2 sourcePoint = curr->source()->point();
    Segment_2 newSegment = Segment_2(sourcePoint, newPoint);
    acc.modify_edge_ex(curr, newSegment);
} while (++curr != first);
```

This is actually partially working (I ensure no overlapping is produced). But as soon as I **change the lexicographically order** of some halfedges endpoints, the `Arrangement::isValid()` returns false.

So my questions are:

1. **Why does changing xy-order destroy the arrangement?** I know this is also documented, but I don't really get why this is important.
2. And: **Is there any way to fix this in my implementation?** I already tried the easier remove vertex / insert vertex method, but that is not really what I want. (I want to keep the faces and their reference / index mapping alive)

Would be really glad if you could help me understand this.

Yours, Salabasti

Answer (score 0):

The direction of every halfedge is cached to expedite frequent operations. The concept ArrangementDcelHalfedge (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classArrangementDcelHalfedge.html#a2bcd73c9eb8383be066161612de98033) requires supporting the methods direction() and set_direction(). So, either you also surgically fix the direction of the affected halfedges using the method set_direction() or you remove these halfedges and then re-insert them. You can retain low complexity by using the specialized insertion functions; see, e.g.,

1. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arrangement__2.html#a88fed7cf475e474d187e65beb894dde2, and
2. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arrangement__2.html#a7b90245d8a42ed90ea13b9d911adac73